How to set layout direction per column in QTableWidget?
I have a QTableWidget with columns of mixed languages (Arabic and English). Since Arabic is RTL and English is LTR, I'd like to set different layout directions per column. I'm aware of the method setLayoutDirection(), but that changes the layout direction for the entire table. RTL direction:

Notice how row #8 reads "Way (Such is Our)". It should be "(Such is Our) Way", but it's reversed because of the layout's direction. If I set the layout's direction to LTR it gets fixed:

(but the whole table moved to the left hand side of the screen, and got flipped).
How can I keep the table at the right side, keep the columns' order intact, but set a different text orientation for each column?
EDIT: Minimal working example:
# LTR
import sys
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem
from PySide6.QtCore import Qt


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        table = QTableWidget(2, 2)
        table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["Arabic", "English"])
        table.setLayoutDirection(Qt.LeftToRight)  # LTR

        table.setItem(0, 0, QTableWidgetItem("(الكلمة الأولى) خلية 1"))
        table.setItem(1, 0, QTableWidgetItem("(الكلمة الثانية) خلية 2"))
        table.setItem(0, 1, QTableWidgetItem("(First word) cell 1"))
        table.setItem(1, 1, QTableWidgetItem("(Second word) cell 2"))

        # Set the table as the central widget
        self.setCentralWidget(table)
        self.setWindowTitle("QTableWidget Example")
        self.resize(400, 300)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())


In the above example I have layout direction set to LTR, and the English looks fine, the Arabic is reversed, and the table is on the left side of the screen:

Same example with RTL layout direction:
table.setLayoutDirection(Qt.RightToLeft)  # RTL



Now the Arabic looks fine, the English is reversed, and the table is on the right side of the screen.
The desired behavior is: the table is on the right side of the screen, neither of the Arabic nor English is reversed.

That text display is probably based on BOM of the returned string, which you probably "changed" in some way or is caused by the source string. Please provide a comprehensive [mre].

@musicamante - I added a minimal working example.

The problem has been reported years ago (see QTBUG-55012) but unfortunately has never been resolved in the API.
It is caused by the fact that when the item text is drawn, it assumes that the displayed text is always consistent with the view's layout direction, but this can cause issues with some characters (notably: parentheses, brackets, etc.).
There are various possible approaches in fixing that, but they all rely on the fact that all left-to-right text strings should always start with a related Unicode text control character when shown in an item view, with the basic \u200e (LEFT-TO-RIGHT MARK) at the beginning of the string being the most obvious choice.
You can add that manually to all hardcoded strings; for instance, in your example code:
    table.setItem(0, 1, QTableWidgetItem("\u200e(First word) cell 1"))
    table.setItem(1, 1, QTableWidgetItem("\u200e(Second word) cell 2"))

Alternatively, you can use a custom delegate that checks the text of each item and tries to guess the layout direction of the string.
class TextDirectionDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def initStyleOption(self, opt, index):
        super().initStyleOption(opt, index)
        if not '\u200e' in opt.text:
            for l in opt.text:
                if bidirectional(l) == 'L':
                    opt.text = '\u200e‎' + opt.text


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        ...
        table.setItemDelegate(TextDirectionDelegate(table))

Note that the above is a very crude implementation and does not consider the possibility of having mixed layout directions (see the answer to this related post for more consistent solutions).
In you case, though, it is clear that specific columns have their own text direction, so there should be no guessing involved: just add the control character in any case, and set the delegate for the related columns.
class TextDirectionDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def initStyleOption(self, opt, index):
        super().initStyleOption(opt, index)
        if not opt.text.startswith('\u200e'):
            opt.text = '\u200e‎' + opt.text


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        ...
        table.setItemDelegateForColumn(1, TextDirectionDelegate(table))


This delegate does the job, without adding extra characters:
class LeftToRightDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        painter.save()
        text_option = QTextOption()
        text_option.setTextDirection(Qt.LayoutDirection.LeftToRight)
        painter.drawText(option.rect, option.displayAlignment, index.data())
        painter.restore()

ltrDelegate = LeftToRightDelegate()
self.setItemDelegateForColumn(1, ltrDelegate)

However, it seems that it overrides the hovering highlight, so that would have to be re-applied. Otherwise the best option would be to append \u200e to the beginning of the text itself, without using a delegate.

Sorry but that's not an effective alternative to what I suggested: while it's true that initStyleOption() is called more often than paint() (making the string update often unnecessary), your implementation completely disregards the default painting of the style, including (but not limited to) basic aspects like item selection or background/foreground colors, making the item appearance inconsistent, unintuitive (no selection highlight) or even unreadable in some cases. Overriding painting for this purpose is inappropriate and ineffective: just add that character and let Qt do the rest.
